# About the statement: The property $(P)$ is not verified for all $n≥m$

Tags: real-analysis, logic

I want to understand this statement:

Let $(P)$ be a property of a real sequence $(u_{n})_{n≥1}$. Consider the case:

**The property $(P)$ is not verified for all $n≥m$**

Here $m$ is positive integer.

My understanding is that the property (P) is not verified for all finite $n$ greater than $m$.

But I am not sure if the property (P) is not verified for infinite $n$, i.e., when $n=+∞$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you say "sequence" or write $(u_n)_{n\ge 1}$ it is implicit that $u_n$ makes sense only when $n$ is a *whole number*. Since $+\infty$ is not a number at all, the notation $(u_n)_{n\ge 1}$ does not promise you that there even is anything called $u_{+\infty}$.

Similarly when one writes "for all $n\ge m$" it is also implicitly understood that we're only talking about whole numbers -- unless it has been very explicitly said that something like $n=+\infty$ is a relevant possibility.

---

On the other hand, the sentence you quote is ambiguous in a different way that you don't seem to be aware of. It could mean either of

- $P(n)$ is not [verified for all $n\ge m$].
- $P(n)$ is [not verified] for all $n\ge m$.

These are different, for example, if $P(n)$ is verified for all *odd* $n$.

Someone who writes such a sentence will usually think it is so bleedingly obvious what is meant that the different interpretation does not even occur to him. But the *reader* may not be so fortunate that he can immeditately reject one of them as pointless in context.

For this reason it is best to be extremely careful about not accidentally writing something ambiguous when you put a "for all $n$" *last*. I it often much clearer to put it *before* the claim about $n$.